# AJAX success is triggered beforer php script sends data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know I am missing something. My problem is that ajax call to a php script and the php script may take a few seconds to gather the information. in the meantime the success is triggered, leaving me with no info on the JS end.

I have an $.ajax as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/dash/assets/functions/canstat.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        recruiter: r,
        status: s,
        state: st,
        type: t,
        cstart: cdb,
        cend: cde,
        sort: sorto,
        prescreener: p
        },
    success: function(data) {
        try {
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#cont').html(display(data));
        } catch (e) {
            alert('Query produced results too large for your browser to display.');
        }
    }
});
```

The return php is as follows:

```
    $result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ar[$i]=$row;
    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($ar);
```

Now there is a possibility that the query would be large, however it would still need to be displayed - per requirements. I do give a warning such as phpMyAdmin gives when clicking "Show All", that the table may crash the browser.

I have tried ob_start(); ob_end_flush(); Different .ini settings. I am at a loss as to what even to search for.

My system is PHP 5.6 on Centos 7

All the PHP code I can produce...

```
    <?php
ob_start();
include_once('../../bs_config.php');
Log::info("REPORTS - Begin");
ini_set("output_buffering","32767");

$search="";
$order = "";

$recruiter=isset($_POST['recruiter'])?$_POST['recruiter']:'0';
$prescreener=isset($_POST['prescreener'])?$_POST['prescreener']:'0';
$status=isset($_POST['status'])?$_POST['status']:'';
$state=isset($_POST['state'])?$_POST['state']:'';
$cstart=isset($_POST['cstart'])?$_POST['cstart']:'';
$cend=isset($_POST['cend'])?$_POST['cend']:'';
$type=isset($_POST['type'])?$_POST['type']:'0';
$sort=isset($_POST['sort'])?$_POST['sort']:'0';


if ($recruiter > "1") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." owner = '$recruiter' AND" : "WHERE owner = '$recruiter' AND";
} else if ($recruiter=="1") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." owner NOT IN ('1251','1259','1267', '1264') AND" : "WHERE owner NOT IN ('1251','1259','1267', '1264') AND";
}
if ($prescreener > "1") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." PreScreener = '$prescreener' AND" : "WHERE PreScreener = '$prescreener' AND";
} else if ($prescreener=="1") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." PreScreener NOT IN ('Woodley, Gary','Follett, Bailey','') AND" : "WHERE PreScreener NOT IN ('Woodley, Gary','Follett, Bailey','') AND";
}
if ($status!="0") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." Status = '$status' AND" : "WHERE Status = '$status' AND";
}
if ($type!="0") {
    switch ($type) {
        case "1": $cos="Attorney"; break;
        case "2": $cos="Legacy"; break;
        case "3": $cos="Alliance America"; break;
        case "4": $cos="IASAR"; break;
    }
    $search=($search!="")? $search." company = '$cos' AND" : "WHERE company = '$cos' AND";
}
if ($state!="") {
    $state="'".$state."'";
    if (strpos($state,',')) {
        $state=str_replace(",","','",$state);
    }
    $search=($search!="")? $search." state IN ($state) AND" : "WHERE state IN ($state) AND";
}
// reset if opposite
if ($cend < $cstart) {
    $cend="";
    $cstart="";
}
if ($cend == "" && $cstart !="") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." date_created > '$cstart' AND" : "WHERE date_created > '$cstart' AND";
}
if ($cend != "" && $cstart =="") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." date_created < '$cend' AND" : "WHERE date_created < '$cend' AND";
}
if ($cend != "" && $cstart !="") {
    $search=($search!="")? $search." (date_created BETWEEN '$cstart' AND '$cend') AND" : "WHERE (date_created BETWEEN '$cstart' AND '$cend') AND";
}

Log::info("Date Begin: ".$cstart);
Log::info("Date End: ".$cend);


// Clean last AND
$search = rtrim($search,' AND');
Log::info("REPORTS: Sort on:".$sort);
// Handle Sorting
switch ($sort) {
    case "1":
        $order = "ORDER BY last_name ASC";
        break;
    case "2":
        $order = "ORDER BY last_name DESC";
        break;
    case "3":
        $order = "ORDER BY first_name ASC";
        break;
    case "4":
        $order = "ORDER BY first_name DESC";
        break;
    case "5":
        $order = "ORDER BY state ASC";
        break;
    case "6":
        $order = "ORDER BY state DESC";
        break;
    case "7":
        $order = "ORDER BY date_created ASC";
        break;
    case "8":
        $order = "ORDER BY date_created DESC";
        break;
    case "9":
        $order = "ORDER BY date_modified ASC";
        break;
    case "10":
        $order = "ORDER BY date_modified DESC";
        break;
    case "11":
        $order = "ORDER BY Status ASC";
        break;
    case "12":
        $order = "ORDER BY Status DESC";
        break;
    case "13":
        $order = "ORDER BY company ASC";
        break;
    case "14":
        $order = "ORDER BY company DESC";
        break;
    case "15":
        $order = "ORDER BY PreScreener ASC";
        break;
    case "16":
        $order = "ORDER BY PreScreener DESC";
        break;
}

// reduce the number of columns to conserve memory
$cols = "candidate_id, last_name, first_name, city, state, zip, Status, owner, date_created, date_modified, company, PreScreener";
$ar = [];
$i=0;
$sql="SELECT $cols FROM candidate ".$search." ".$order;

Log::info("REPORTS - ".$sql);

$result=$conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ar[$i]=$row;
    Log::dump($i,$row);
    $i++;
}


echo json_encode($ar);
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: what is the content of data?

Comment: have you initialized `$i` in php script?

Comment: Do you have your entire PHP file? Check to see if you've started output at the start of your script (for example, a whitespace at the beginning of your page).

Comment: That sounds rather impossible (success triggering before the request was answered.) Much more likely that you took the wrong conclusion from what you are trying to do with the data throwing an exception, I think ...? Log `e` to console and inspect it, to first of all see what kind of error you are actually dealing with here!

Comment: How many records?....how about implementing pagination?

Comment: please put php code

Comment: Also, which database are you using?...are you aware of `limit offset, row_count`?

Comment: remove $i and use $ar[]

Comment: The query can possibly produce 30,000 rows, 8 columns... the ob_start is at the top of the script, I can't post all the code, but I can say that when ajax sends a request that will return around 1000 rows, all is fine. I made a log entry in the array loop to assemble the json array and I watch the log continue for about 20 seconds after my  alert message comes up in the success (meaning that json.PARSE failed) so I cannot see how any information is being sent yet. I agree this is strange.

Comment: Just use $ar[]=$row; .... don't need $i

Comment: var_dump out  $result->fetch_assoc()    Is there a result?

Comment: run your raw SQL in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin, Does it work?

Comment: yes it comes up in phpMyAdmin, I had the i++ in there because I was sending other information back, just for grins I took it out.  I may have to implement pagnation - but I want to know why the success is getting fired off before the output is sent.. That seems like an issue to me.

Comment: _"watch the log continue for about 20 seconds after my alert message comes up in the success"_ - that's strange indeed. Sounds like actually some buffer content might have gotten flushed - but the browser should nevertheless not misinterpret a partial response as "the full thing" ... Can you check in network panel, what the "end" of the response data looks like? Does that just seem "cut off", are there any PHP warnings in there maybe? I suppose a `Content-Length` header might not be part of the response? Anything else suspicious? `Connection: Close` part of it maybe?

Comment: It is very strange. I do not know how to see the headers come in, but the php has ob_start(); on the first line.I will try adding the headers in the response "Content-Length" but I have never came across this before. I do see the canstat.php file appearing 3 times in the network tab of dev tools.

Comment: Don't you have other ajax being triggered at the same time? When you checkout the network tab on the elements inspect, what is in there? what it says?

Comment: no I do not have other ajax. I have solved the problem by forcing pagnation. But seeing this issue I want to understand why. I have never seen this behavior.